# SQL: SELECT data from an INSERT done within a SQL Transaction that is not yet committed

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have a old application written in C# which

1. Initiates a SQL transaction
2. Does an `INSERT` using petapoco. Key for the inserted recorded in generated via custom logic (no identity insert)
3. Then does a `SELECT` of the inserted record using the generated keys using petapoco - `first<dynamic>` (SQL)
4. Pushes the record via an API
5. Commits the transaction.

Issue is the `SELECT` statement in Step 3 that reads the inserted record; it is working fine in one SQL Server, but not the other.

I ran SQL Server Profiler trace and was not able to find any discrepancy. Isolation level is `READ COMMITTED` without snapshot.

Can you suggest possible areas where I can investigate further?

Comment: `Issue is the SELECT statement in Step 3 that reads the inserted record is working fine in one sql server but not the other.` can you please elaborate on what do you mean by `one sql server but not the other` and `working fine`

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _working fine in one sql server but not the other_. Can you post the relevant SQL code (eg copy from SQL Profiler)? If you are able to pause the code after Step 2, then you can check if the record was successfully inserted a query with `WITH (NOLOCK)`, eg: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE clause_to_show_recent_records = 1 WITH(NOLOCK)`

Comment: I have two SQL servers (QA and Staging environments). I set a break point at after Step 2 (after the insert) in the C# code and did a SELECT from SQL Mgmt Studio using the generated keys. One of the SQL server returns the inserted record while the other server returns 0 records. The second server acts as if the INSERT did not happen but SQL profiler shows that the insert statement got executed successfully.

Comment: Assuming that you paused right after step 2, then unless you run your select with `WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)` you will not see anything as transaction has not committed yet. If you do, then it means transaction has committed already, and did not wait for step 5.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but the transaction is initiated via petapoco.   var row = DownSyncData.SyncTransaction.First<dynamic>(sql);.   Also the issue of not able to retrieve the record is happening only in SQL Server 2016. My other server where the SELECT statement is returning rows is SQl Sever 2008 r2. Anyhow I have made the code change to not call the SELECT inside the transaction block. Would still like to know what is causing the difference.